# Configuring Glassfish without admin console gui

Tags: configuration, glassfish, openshift

I have installed Glassfish application server Openshift cloud servers. I can only use :8080 port because of Openshift restrictions. It won't let me run admin console on :4848 port and I will somehow configure datasource, file realm and security realm manually from configuration files.

a-) Is it possible to do configuration without the admin console?

b-) Can admin console run on :8080 port along with applications?

Note: It is not possible to allocate any port for admin console Openshift won't let me do it.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

a) You can configure Glassfish with the [asadmin tool](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2416/giobi.html)

b) You can change the port for the admin console in glassfish/domains/[yourdomain]/config/domain.xml: search for

```
<network-listener port="4848" protocol="admin-listener" transport="tcp" name="admin-listener" thread-pool="admin-thread-pool"></network-listener>
```

But I doubt it is possible to use port 8080 for admin gui AND other applications.

Comment: a) asadmin tool doesn't work when I comment network listener for admin-listener in domain.xml file. The error is : Remote server does not listen for requests on [localhost:4848]. Is the server up?
No such local command, list-applications. To run remote commands, start the application server (e.g. 'asadmin start-domain').
Command list-applications failed. b)It is not possible to allocate any port for admin console Openshift won't let me do it. (So changing port is not the solution it won't run) Thanks

Comment: I have done configuration on the domain.xml file, without using the admin console. Cheers