# Error while starting GoldFish server: Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: java, ubuntu, web-applications, glassfish

I consulted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21009656/glassfish-war-file-deployment-to-a-non-default-port) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13793028/configuring-glassfish-without-admin-console-gui) but could not get my problem solved.

When I type this on terminal `/opt/glassfish4/glassfish/bin/asadmin start`, I get the following result:

```
Remote server does not listen for requests on [localhost:4848]. Is the server up?
Unable to get remote commands. 
Closest matching local command(s): 
    restart-domain
    restart-local-instance
    start-database
    start-domain
    start-local-instance

Command start failed.
```

Similarly, when I type this `/opt/glassfish4/glassfish/bin/asadmin --port 5656 start-domain`, I get

```
java.io.IOException: Couldn't get lock for /opt/glassfish4/glassfish/domains/domain1/logs/server.log
    at java.util.logging.FileHandler.openFiles(FileHandler.java:389)
    at java.util.logging.FileHandler.<init>(FileHandler.java:287)
    at com.sun.enterprise.admin.launcher.GFLauncherLogger.addLogFileHandler(GFLauncherLogger.java:98)
    at com.sun.enterprise.admin.launcher.GFLauncher.setup(GFLauncher.java:191)
    at com.sun.enterprise.admin.servermgmt.cli.StartDomainCommand.createLauncher(StartDomainCommand.java:220)
    at com.sun.enterprise.admin.servermgmt.cli.StartDomainCommand.executeCommand(StartDomainCommand.java:117)
    at com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.CLICommand.execute(CLICommand.java:321)
    at com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.AdminMain.executeCommand(AdminMain.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.AdminMain.doMain(AdminMain.java:298)
    at org.glassfish.admin.cli.AsadminMain.main(AsadminMain.java:56)
Waiting for domain1 to start .Error starting domain domain1.
The server exited prematurely with exit code 1.
Before it died, it produced the following output:

Launching GlassFish on Felix platform
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: the domain directory is not writable.
    at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.MainHelper.verifyDomainRoot(MainHelper.java:244)
    at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.MainHelper.findInstanceRoot(MainHelper.java:347)
    at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.GlassFishMain.main(GlassFishMain.java:78)
    at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.ASMain.main(ASMain.java:54)

Command start-domain failed.
```

I sense there is something problem in path `/opt/glassfish4/glassfish/bin/asadmin`. I am working on my first JSF web application and cannot run glassfish server. I am using Netbeans and ubuntu 13.10.
Can anyone show me the way?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error messages

> java.io.IOException: Couldn't get lock for
>   /opt/glassfish4/glassfish/domains/domain1/logs/server.log

and

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: the domain
>   directory is not writable.

indicate that the user account you use to start the server doesn't have write permissions in your Glassfish domain folder.

To solve the problem either change the permissions or start the `asadmin` command with a user who has sufficient permissions.

If this doesn't solve the problem, there may be another process which has a lock on your `server.log` file, but I guess you would have noticed that. To make sure you can run

```
lsof /opt/glassfish4/glassfish/domains/domain1/logs/server.log
```

to see if any process is using the file.

**See also:**

- [Failed to start glassfish server because Couldn't get lock for /opt/glassfishv3/glassfish/domains/domain1/logs/server.log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24447579/failed-to-start-glassfish-server-because-couldnt-get-lock-for-opt-glassfishv3)